# Select records with less than N associations that do not have particular association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have following models:

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :image
  validates :image_id, uniqueness: { scope: [ :user_id] }    
end    

class Image < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :ratings    
end    

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :images, through: :ratings    
end
```

Users are rating the images. I want to get the images that are not rated by a particular user, and that are rated by less than 3 users in total. Right now I'm showing those images that are rated by minimal number of user. I've done this with cache counter:

```
@image = Image.order(:ratings_count).first
```

Part I'm having problems with is how to get the Images that are not rated by current user. Would appreciate any help. Number of queries is not that important, as long as it's the Ruby Way to get this records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this obviously, this is one way.

```
already_rated = Rating.where(user_id: 1).pluck(:image_id)
yet_to_be_rated = Image.where('id not in (?)', already_rated)
```

Comment: it should be: `Image.where('id not in (?)', already_rated)` 
But thanks!

Comment: There is a way to do this in one query, I just don't have Rails on my present computer to play with. But the query would be something like `Image.joins(:rating).where( ratings: { user_id: 1 }).` and so on

Comment: Tried that and a lot of similar joins and includes. The problem is that with this you get images rated by this user. But if you try to negate it, it will return images rated by other users, not images that are not rated by this user.

Comment: Spot on, it just depends on your situation whether it's ok performance wise to it in two queries or one. Then there is always the possibility of using `find_by_sql`.